# Program or the command type does not support user interaction

Tags: c#, powershell

I am running PowerShell scripts from C# successfully. In some instances I receive the following message:

> A program that prompts a user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message "insert message here".

Here's a real example of the message:

[image: example message]

I would like to handle and be able to respond to such prompts in the C# application.

Here's the code I am successfully running to execute PS scripts:

```cs
private ICollection<PSObject> PSExecute()
{
    InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
    string script = @"C:\script\";

    using (Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss))
    {
        runSpace.Open();
        //using (Pipeline pipeLine = runSpace.CreatePipeline())
        using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powershell.Runspace = runSpace;
            var ps = powershell.AddScript(script);
            var results = powershell.Invoke();
            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

I am looking for a way to extend this so that I can handle and pass such prompts to the C# application e.g. to a MessageBox so the user can respond.

Comment: You should implement `System.Management.Automation.Host.PSHost` and pass instance of it into `RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace` method.

Comment: Thanks! Any chance you could provide an example?